# Disable user input when menu is active?

Tags: android

I currently have a slide out menu from the left of the screen and am using this method for anyone who's interested:

[Facebook lide slideout menu (Not using that library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328895/facebook-lide-slideout-menu-not-using-that-library)

[Android - Animate a View's topMargin/bottomMargin/etc in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239442/android-animate-a-views-topmargin-bottommargin-etc-in-linearlayout-or-relativ)

Once the menu comes out, it only covers 3/4 of the screen and I'm still showing my main activity in the other 1/4 of the screen. But I'm trying to sort of 'freeze' the main activity when my onMenuClick is fired.. because right now even if the menu is opened, the user can still scroll around and click on things in that 1/4 of the screen.

Once I get this working I'll just set it to close the menu if they click anywhere on the main activity, but for now I'm just trying to disable the input when the menu is opened, then enable the input again when the menu is closed. I know there's a way to take a capture so to speak of the current 'screen' and render it on the screen as a 'locked image' so to speak.. I've done it before but can't remember how I did it.

If anyone has done something like this and remembers how they achieved it any help is appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rightLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        if(lhsMenu.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
           // Close the menu
           return;
        } else {
           // Handle the click normally
           super.onClick(v);
        }
});
```

The rightLayout and lhsMenu are taken from the link you posted in the question.