# How to animate (move) a view above another view that becomes visible?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using a RelativeLayout to stack a view A above a view B that is hidden (GONE). When the user clicks on view A, I want view A to slowly move upwards and then show view B (VISIBLE).

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Why your view B is GONE and not INVISIBLE?

Comment: Because then my view B would use space

Comment: You can have the view A above view B in a RelativeLayout also if view B use space. What's the question? How to move A or how to inflate B under A?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Android Animators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html). You can also google for something like "android animator position", you'll find tons of examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195575/android-animating-view-position) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016674/android-translate-animation-permanently-move-view-to-new-position-using-animat).

Answer (score 1):

For animating A you can use Animation class (and its subclasses) or Animator classes (such as ObjectAnimator, which animates a property of the view)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html